# How to make a live Twitterfeed like Google IO 2011 application?

Tags: android, twitter, feed, tweets

I don't know if you already tested the Google IO application, but there is a cool feature displaying all the tweets including Google IO hashtags.

I really would like to offer the same feature to my users.

I can do something similar using the API, but I would have to create a custom listview, parsing XML/JSON feeds and that's quite overcomplicated! **and of course this list will not update automatically and be a livefeed**.

In the application, I have just seen that when I turn off wifi, This is indeed a webview with this url:

http://www.google.com/search?%20tbs=mbl%3A1&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1170&bih=668&q=%23io2011&btnG=Search

Here is a screenshot of the app and the same url in the browser

High resolution picture: http://cl.ly/3q1r0c2J3H163E3G2p2X

[image: Hi resolution, click Here]

But using this url in a webview display only a google search, and does not offer same feature.

I know this app will certainly be opensources, but i am so negative about "within next days" that google promise.
We are still waiting for the Twitter app source code!

Comment: For clarification:  If you already know what the URL used in the WebView is, and you can easily use that to construct a URL with your own query, what else are you looking for?

Comment: I added a screenshot: within the app, it display pictures, etc.. and in the browser or in a webview, that's a classic Google search.

Answer (score 1):

If you wait 'til after the conference is over, you'll find the source code for the app [here](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/). You'll also find last year's application's source code there.

### Update:

Just viewed the source code, and you're almost right. It's a webview with this URL: http://www.google.com/search?tbs=mbl%3A1&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1170&bih=668&q=%23io2011&btnG=Search so it just seems you put %20 in there by accident maybe.

Code:

```
public static final String EXTRA_QUERY = "com.google.android.iosched.extra.QUERY";

public static final String CONFERENCE_HASHTAG = "#io2011";

private String mSearchString;

//onCreate()
final Intent intent = BaseActivity.fragmentArgumentsToIntent(getArguments());
mSearchString = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_QUERY);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchString)) {
    mSearchString = CONFERENCE_HASHTAG;
}
if (!mSearchString.startsWith("#")) {
    mSearchString = "#" + mSearchString;
}

//onCreateView
mWebView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webview);

mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        try {
            mWebView.loadUrl(
                    "http://www.google.com/search?tbs="
                    + "mbl%3A1&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1170&bih=668&q="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(mSearchString, "UTF-8")
                    + "&btnG=Search");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not construct the realtime search URL", e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Seem that the code will not help me: http://twitter.com/#!/romannurik/statuses/69818965840506880

Answer (score 0):

Probably implemented with [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) API with throttling.
Impatiently waiting for source code as well.